# Any [hint] what is wrong with these tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

It looks like there are a few [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hint) tags:

1. [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hint)
2. [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hints)
3. [code-hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-hinting)

[image: tag search screenshot]

What is the difference between those tags? Are they duplicates?

Comment: Looks like you need a hint to answer that question? :P You can check the questions tagged with those. It currently looks like they are used for any kind of "hint" without any clear distinction.

Comment: Sounds like a good basis for a [meta-tag:synonym-request]

Comment: Looking at the oldest question tagged with them, looks like both '[hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117301/how-does-including-a-sql-index-hint-affect-query-performance)' and '[hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265516/hints-in-sql-server)' were intended for DB/SQL-related, while '[code-hinting`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061996/flex-builder-3-code-hints)' was related to IDE functionality.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I disagree with synonym-request.  After about 30 minutes browsing the three tags there are three distinct meanings.

Comment: I only meant that it should be tagged as such and formalized as one (upon further inspection, I agree with your assessmemt - it should be a disambiguation request) to show up in burnination feeds + become actionable, since those tags definitely need work.

Comment: How can we move forward with fixing this?

Answer (score 15):

Taking a look at [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hint), the majority of questions appear to be pre-populated text for a UI, including:

- the `android:hint` element in `EditText`.
- `Application.OnHint` in Delphi
- placeholders in fields in Java Swing

Two significant minority groups appear:

- SQL statements (Oracle and T-SQL) giving [compiler hints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (but this appears to be the plural [hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hints)).
- IDE autocomplete hints ([IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode), [PhpStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpStorm), and linters), but these appear to be what [code-hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-hinting) is meant for.

So while [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hint) is somewhat ambiguous, the existence of the other tags is more clear and some [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hint) questions could be retagged to clean it up.   And some tag descriptions/wikis should document this for future questioners.

Comment: The OnHint event in Delphi is just a local flavour of the language-independent GUI item "hint box" that appears when you mouse-over something. I'm not sure how common the term is elsewhere, but at least Delphi's sibling product C++ Builder uses the same term.

Comment: @Lundin The common term for that is tooltip.

Comment: @MrLister Yeah so this might be ambiguous with Delphi having used this term for ages before de facto standard names emerged. Delphi was a pioneer in GUI design in the early 90s, so there will be lots of archaic terms still.

Comment: I just fired up a semi-recent version of C++ Builder to check and the property name is still `hint`. And there's a `CustomHint` class in Delphi/C++ Builder, used for tool tips. Funny that they use the terms tool bar and tool button, but not tool tip for the box that appears when you place the mouse over a tool button :)

Comment: This is a very ambiguous and useless tag, why is there no proposal for removing  it?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe feel free to write your own proposal in another answer.